# Specifying which channel to send chat from a discord bot (say-channel command)

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

It's a feature that's found in [GLaDOS](https://discordbots.org/bot/glados) bot, the [Connor RK800](https://discordbots.org/bot/467913111551082518) bot, and the [TypicalBot](https://bots.discord.pw/bots/153613756348366849).

Often the command appears like this:

!say #general heck

And the text, through the bot, will appear in that channel.

I'd like to add this to my own bot, if possible!

I have a bare-bones code for the say-delete command. What will I have to add, and what will I have to take away?

```
      if (command === "say") {
  const sayMessage = args.join(" ");

  message.delete().catch(O_o => {
    // Catch error
  });
  message.channel.send(sayMessage);
}
```

Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Comment: You used the tag "discord.js" and "discord.io". Which library are you now using? :)

Comment: I'm using discord.js. Sorry if the tags were confusing -- I am brand new to this site! I'll fix it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First, you would want to change the code for defining the arguments in this case to `const channel = args.shift();`, which will return the first item in the args[] array.

Then you can identify the channel the user wants to send the message to with `message.guild.channels[channel].send(sayMessage);` (I think).

All together, your code would be:

```
if(command === "say") {

   const channel = args.shift();
   const sayMessage = args.join(" ");

   message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});  

   message.guild.channels[channel].send(sayMessage);

}
```

As I can't check this right now, I don't know for sure if this would work, but it's worth a shot! If you'd like I can test it for you once I am able to.

EDIT:
I tested and fixed the code, hopefully the comments I have written are explanatory enough.

```
const channel = args.shift().slice(2,-1); // this is due to how channel mentions work in discord (they are sent to clients as <#462650628376625169>, this cuts off the first <# and the finishing >)
const sayMessage = args.join(` `);

message.delete(); // you may want to add a catch() here, i didn't because my bot requires permissions to be added to a server
client.channels.get(channel).send(sayMessage); // client here may need to be replaced with bot, or app, or whatever you're using - client.channels returns a collection, which we use get() to find an item in
```

Just to be clear, this code will have to go within your `if (command === "say")` block.

Comment: I tested it out, and it doesn’t work. At first, I thought it was because of the message-delete line, but it still doesn’t work afterwards. But thank you so much, yogsoy! If you can, it would be absolutely great if you can test it out. Once again, this is much appreciated.

Comment: Updated the code, you might want to try testing it again. Note that it only works right now if you mention it by typing a # and the name of the channel with the selector that pops up - just typing "#channel" won't work.

Comment: It’s fully functional now. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
// making the say command
const sayCommand = `${prefix}say`
// say command
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${sayCommand}`)) {
        // declaring args variable
        const args = message.content.slice(sayCommand.length).split(/ +/);
        // delcaring sayMessage that clears the say command from the say message
        let sayMessage = args.join(` `);
        // deletes the command message
        message.delete();
        // bot sends the contents of the command without the say command
        message.channel.send(sayMessage)
    }
```

this works for me verry well